# Is it possible to run "mysqld" without installation in Linux?

Tags: mysql, linux

I have run `mysqld.exe` in Windows to run the server without installation. I am able to connect to it via a client and everything works fine.

Is it possible to do the same in Linux? Can we run `mysqld` without complete installation of the whole MySQL package. I tried several ways but failed.

Answer (score 1):

Q: Is it possible to run “mysqld” without installation in Linux?

A: Short answer: no.

The mysqld executable depends on shared libraries, and on runtime configuration of several different files in several different locations.

Q: Is it possible to create an embedded mySQL configuration, in lieu of the standard install?

A: Depending on your requirements, this might be something you wish to investigate:

- https://www.mysql.com/oem/

Comment: What if I can ensure that the runtime configuration of several different files is alright? Can I run it without installation in such a case?

Comment: @PankajDwivedi Why? All you're asking is really how to replicant what the installer does. Where's the value in that?

Answer (score 0):

The **Bitnami** stack provides what you need.

https://bitnami.com/tag/mysql

Basically, they provide self-contained *packages* for the different services that are normally available through apt, yum or any other packages manager. I use it for example to install Redmnine (BUG tracking system) and the installation was straightforward.

The good thing is that the installation process doesn't affect your current system (packages, shared libraries etc) since all the dependencies: packages, shared libraries, etc are installed in a single directory. Thus, it's very easy to install, test and delete the whole thing easily if you would like to.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what you mean by *"without complete installation of the whole MySQL package"*... the answer is **yes.**

As a DBA, I don't trust package management to manipulate my MySQL installations, so I *never* install MySQL Server from package management.

I manage everything myself, and essentially everything is stored under `/usr/local/mysql` from the Linux Generic binary tarball.  There is nothing really "installed" in the sense of mystery files added who-knows-where on the system.  Upgrades involve extracting a new tarball and creating a new symlink for the datadir.

The only external dependency is easily resolved with `$ sudo apt-get install libaio1`.

Comment: Well, hmmm... thanks to whoever for the downvote without a comment to explain. lol, maybe I don't manage dozens of MySQL servers on a daily basis, and perhaps I haven't been working with MySQL Server for almost 15 years, the last 5 as a DBA.  Ah, Stack Overflow.